# Finding all $\mathbb{C}$-algebra homomorphisms $\mathbb{C}[x^2, y^2]\to\mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I am interested in calculating all $\mathbb{C}$-algebra homomorphisms from $\mathbb{C}[x^2, y^2]\to\mathbb{C}$. I understand that every $\mathbb{C}$-algebra homomorphism will fix $\mathbb{C}$ and send $x^2$ and $y^2$ somewhere in $\mathbb{C}$. But I don't exactly understand how do we "send" $x^2$ and $y^2$ to $\mathbb{C}$. Do we send $x$ and $y$ somewhere first?

I know how to answer the exact same question for $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$. Namely, every $\mathbb{C}$-algebra homomorphism $\mathbb{C}[x,y]\to\mathbb{C}$ is determined by where the generators are sent. Since $x, y$ can freely go to any point in $\mathbb{C}$, we see that there is a one-to-one correspondence between the set of all $\mathbb{C}$-algebra homomorphisms $\mathbb{C}[x,y]\to\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{C}^2$.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Isn't the natural mapping $\Bbb C[x,y]\to\Bbb C[x^2,y^2]$ an isomorphism?

Comment: @Berci: I am assuming you mean $x\mapsto x^2$, $y\mapsto y^2$. I can see that this map will be surjective. I think the tricky part is to show it is injective, which user rghthndsd have done below using some dimension theory. But the statement is so intuitive, I wonder if there might be easier way...

Comment: If $g(x,y)$ is not the 0 polynom, then of course also $g(x^2,y^2)$ is not the 0 polynom (as being the 0 polynom only depends on the coefficients) - as you are over $\mathbb{C}$, $g(x^2, y^2)$ will even never induce the $0$-homomorphism.

So I don't see the problem with showing that this map is injective.

Comment: @Louis: Thanks! That's it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edited to add: I forgot to directly answer the following question: "Do we send $x$ and $y$ somewhere first?" The answer is no: $x$ and $y$ aren't even in the ring $\mathbb{C}[x^2, y^2]$. By definition, this ring only has *even* powers of $x$ and $y$.

In your example of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$, you mention "Since $x,y$ can freely go to any point in $\mathbb{C}$..." Why is this? It's because there are no nonzero relations (polynomials) that $x$ and $y$ satisfy. For $\mathbb{C}[x^2,y^2]$ perhaps this isn't as obvious. A common way to show this is by using dimension theory for rings, but perhaps one can prove it just using the definition.

Define the map $\varphi : \mathbb{C}[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}[x^2,y^2]$ by sending $a \rightarrow x^2$ and $b \rightarrow y^2$ which is a surjective homomorphism (show this if it isn't obvious!). Now we have to ask what the kernel is. It turns out to be $(0)$, and one can see this by noting that $\mathbb{C}[x^2, y^2]$ has dimension at least 2: $(0) \subset (x^2) \subset (x^2, y^2)$ being a chain of prime ideals. If the kernel was nonzero, then the dimension of $\mathbb{C}[a,b]/ \text{ker} \varphi \cong \mathbb{C}[x^2,y^2]$ would be less than 2, a contradiction. We have just shown
$$\mathbb{C}[a,b] \cong \mathbb{C}[x^2,y^2]$$
and from here the answer to your question should be easy.

The same technique as above works on other examples. Try $\mathbb{C}[x^2,xy,y]$ for fun. The chain of prime ideals in this case will be $(0) \subset (y) \subset (x^2,y)$.

Comment: Are $a,b$ in your answer above any indeterminates?

Comment: Thanks for this great answer (+1). Could you clarify this sentence: "If the kernel was nonzero, then the dimension of $\mathbb{C}[a,b]/ \text{ker} \varphi \cong \mathbb{C}[x^2,y^2]$ would be less than 2"? If the kernel is nonzero, I am guessing "dimension" of kernel will be at least 1, from which $\mathbb{C}[a,b]/\text{ker} \varphi$ would have dimension at most 1. Is this the reasoning you had in mind?

Comment: Yes, one may use $x$ and $y$ if you prefer. I like to be able to keep track of which side of the homomorphism you are on.

Comment: @Prism Yes, that's it. To be a little more precise: since $\mathbb{C}[x^2,y^2]$ is an integral domain, we know the kernel is a prime ideal. Futhermore, we have the following theorem: For any finitely generated $k$ ($k = \mathbb{C}$ here) algebra $A$ and prime ideal $P$ we have $\dim A = \text{ht} P + \dim(A/P)$. If $\ker \varphi \neq 0$, then $0 \subset \ker \varphi$ is a chain of prime ideals making $\text{ht} \ker \varphi \geq 1$ and therefore $\dim \mathbb{C}[a,b] > 2$, but the dimension of $\mathbb{C}[a,b] = 2$.

Comment: Ah that makes sense! Thanks for the clarification :)